# exec not working with java 1.7.21, but in netbeans works fine

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, runtime, exec

I made a little program and it worked fine, but now. First, it mux the xml chapter file in the mkv file, so we get a muxed mkv file. Some day ago I updated java to 1.7.21 and I think this is the problem why it is not working now. It's a little strange, but when I run in netbeans everything is fine, but when I build and I run the .jar file, it is not working. It create the xml file, but not mux in the mkv file (and because not muxed not delete the xml file). Here is the code: (filename=xml file path; mkv=mkv file path)

```
    public void muxing() {
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = rt.exec("c:\\Program Files\\MKVtoolnix\\mkvpropedit.exe --chapters \""+filename+"\" \""+mkv+"\"");
        if (p.waitFor()==0) {
            File xmlfile=new File(filename);
            xmlfile.delete();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The program worked with java 1.6 and I think with 1.7.17 too. Win7 32bit. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle has made [breaking changes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u21-relnotes-1932873.html#jruntime) to `Runtime.exec()` in Java 7 update 21 (and 6 update 45).

If the program name contains spaces, you need to specify command and arguments in an array:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
    "C:\\Program Files\\MKVtoolnix\\mkvpropedit.exe",
    "--chapters", "\""+filename+"\"", "\""+mkv+"\""});
```

Another option is to use `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\MKVtoolnix\\mkvpropedit.exe",
    "--chapters", "\""+filename+"\"", "\""+mkv+"\"").start();
```

As stated by Oracle:

> Applications that need to launch programs with spaces in the program name should consider using the variants of `Runtime.exec` that allow the command and arguments to be specified in an array.
>
> Alternatively, the preferred way to create operating systems processes since JDK 5.0 is using `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`. The ProcessBuilder class has a much more complete API for setting the environment, working directory and redirecting streams for the process.

Comment: Thank you! Working perfectly! I suspected what the problem but I didn't know what is it exactly.

Comment: Note that they made the same Process.exec change in 1.6.0_45